# How did the preposition "de" evolve into meaning "from"?

Tags: preposition, ablative, proto-indo-european

I see that in reconstructed PIE "de" or "do" has a meaning of "towards" which is retained in Germanic "to" and Slavic "do". But in Latin "de" has a meaning of "from". Is that simply due it taking the Ablative case (i.e. it meant "towards" unless used with Ablative and finally was only used in that capacity)?